# Connect a expression and a variable in a regex

Tags: regex, perl

I want to do something like this

```
 if($variable =~ /$other_variable_expression/){
     do something;
 }
```

where `$other_variable` is a dynamic part(changed by a loop etc.) and `expression` is a static part like "abc" always!

How to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two ways:

```
/${other_variable}_expression/
```

or

```
/$other_variable\_expression/
```